When running selenium in docker, when will chrome automatically exit?
I am using docker image is the standalone-chrome officially provided by selenium, connecting to the webdriver in this container through Remote, and then the program runs locally, which is equivalent to the webdriver on the remote end. In my local program, I do not want my selenium program to close the webdriver after it ends. I'm not sure when this webdriver will shut down automatically, but I found that it will really shut down.
This container has been running, but the webdriver in it has exited. When you remote it, a new chrome will be started.
I want to be able to tell me how long it will take before the webdriver automatically shuts down, and how I can control this time.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
